# Get the latest committed files using GIT

Tags: git, github

I searched a lot online, but could not find a conclusive answer for this. 
I am doing the following steps on a dir to add it to git

```
git add SomeDir/
git commit -m "Some Message"
git diff --name-only HEAD~1

fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Was this the first commit in that repository? If so, then `HEAD~1` doesn't exist - there is no other commit before it. You might want `git log -1 --name-only` instead of `git diff --name-only HEAD~1`.

Comment: If this commit is the very first commit of a newly created repository, `git diff --name-only HEAD~1` should not work as `HEAD~1`(means *parent commit of current commit*) does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have a HEAD? If you run this command:

```
git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline
```

is one of your commits labeled HEAD? If not, then the problem is that git doesn't know to which commit you're referring. You might need to change to use a different label (such as the hash).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to see the diff between your commit and origin? If so, the command would be

```
git diff master origin/master --name-only
```

Alternatively, you could also use

```
git diff --cached
```

to diff between the staging area and HEAD.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I want to the get the last committed files by the developer. I dont want to find a diff between the master and origin.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you're looking for. You just want to be able to see which files have been changed in the latest commit?

Comment: yes, I am sorry if the question is a bit hazy. I just want to keep a track of the files that have been changed.

Comment: Alright. Now, has the developer pushed the changes to Github (origin)? Or is the commit local and you're trying to see what the new files in the local commit are?

Comment: The commit is local, and I am trying to see the new files in the local commit.

Comment: Right, then you *are* trying to compare against the commit in origin (to see what's changed since the last push). Try using the first command I listed, but replace "master" with whatever the name of the branch you're currently on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32518/discussion-between-eric-palace-and-anonymous123)

Answer (score 0):

So after loads of researching, this is what I found, to find all the files in your last commit to git, not a push, but just a local commit type

```
git show --name-only
```